# jQuery load and change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a 'test.html' and a 'test.php' files.

The 'test.html':

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("p").on('click', function() {
      $(this).load("test.php");
      $(this).off();
    });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#sel_1").on('change', function() {
      alert("SELECT changed!");
    });
  });
</script>
```

And the 'test.php':

```
<?php
  echo "<select id='sel_1'>";
  echo "<option>one</option>";
  echo "<option>two</option>";
  echo "<option>three</option>";
  echo "</select>";
?>
```

When i click the 'p' item (Hello), then the jQuery load a new content into 'p'.

But when i change a select item, I would like to see the alert messages, but it will not appear.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Use delegate for this

Comment: it's better use a class <select class="select-class"> and $(".select-class").on("change".....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('body').on('change', "#sel_1", function() {
      alert("SELECT changed!");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, it really works!

Answer (score 2):

As others mentionned, you need to use event delegation.

Here is a **[small example](http://jsfiddle.net/newblt123/ZwULd/1/)**:

html:

```
<div>
    Hello
</div>

<button> Add Content </button>
```

javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("button")
        .on('click', function () {
            $("div")
                .append(getSelect());
        });

    $("div")
        .on('change', '.mySelects', function () {
            alert('select changed!');
        });
});

function getSelect() {
    return $("<select></select>")
        .addClass("mySelects")
        .append($("<option></option>")
            .html("abc")
            .val("1"))
        .append($("<option></option>")
            .html("def")
            .val("2"));
}
```